# Copy data from Excel to MS Word

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I sometimes do not get the full data from excel into the word document. It works for the first, second, third word document, then only 1 word in the 4th, 5th, and 6th and then again the full info into the 7th document - as an example.

I am wondering why the macro works ok sometimes for all documents, sometimes only for a few - copying only the last word - without the template & logo.

The code I'm using is:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim UsedRng As Range
Dim FirstRow As Integer, LastRow As Integer

Dim appWD As Object
Set appWD = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    appWD.Visible = True


Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    FirstRow = UsedRng(1).Row
    LastRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row

Sheets("Data").Select
'FinalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To LastRow

    If Range("F" & i).Value = "Yes" Then
        'SRange = Range("F" & i).Value
        Range("A" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("C5").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Sheets("Data").Select
        Range("D" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("C6").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        Sheets("Data").Select
        Range("J" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("C7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

        Sheets("Data").Select
        Range("L" & i, "N" & i).Copy
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("C8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=True

        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("A1:D11").Copy

        appWD.Documents.Add
        appWD.Selection.Paste
        appWD.ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:="MS_ST" & i
        appWD.ActiveDocument.Close
        Sheets("Letter").Select
        Range("C5:C11").ClearContents
    End If
    Sheets("Data").Select
Next i
appWD.Quit
Set appWD = Nothing

End Sub
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, throw anything at me as I'm looking to learn more and always improve. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: Does the malfunction occur always for the same values of `i`?

Comment: Have you tried setting a break point in your code so that you can check what's actually in the Range you're copying (A1:D11)?  Click in that line and press F9 to set the break point. The code will stop executing and you should be able to look at the worksheet. That should tell you whether the problem is in how the code for Excel is working, or if the problem is in the transfer to Word.

Comment: The Excel code is working ok. The problem seems to be in the transfer to Word. It only copies one cell instead of the 4 designated and it doesn't even copy the excel template i.e. data. The error is for different values of i, usually for the ones after 5. Sometimes, no error occurs, so all data is transferred & saved ok. The Word docs get created but with missing data - when the error occurs.